# If misplaced cowl is causing windshield to break, will replacing it fix the windshield issue?

Tags: windshield

The last two times I had my windshield replaced, it developed cracks from each corner not long after. When I replaced my battery recently, the guy at the store noticed and realized the cracks seemed to be originating due to the cowl piece. IT's a 2003 suzuki xl7.

Basically it seems to be misplaced so that it creates pressure on the glass when the hood is opened and then cracks the glass. I don't know much about this so I don't know if I just have to shift the piece (the cowl itself I think is undamaged) or if I'd need to replace and reinstall. I think the cowl just sits too low? It's not a part I've ever paid much attention to before!

Has anyone had this problem before? I am really hoping for a simple fix and would appreciate any advice!

Comment: Tell us what model of car (or bike?) you have, otherwise nobody can answer the question. FWIW based on the cars I've owned, I can't imagine what this "cowl piece" actually is - opening the hood doesn't move anything that goes anywhere near the windscreen.

Comment: Pictures would be great!